# Is an overlay more susceptible to phishing?

Tags: javascript, overlay, phishing

Working on a web development project, functionality requires a user to navigate through the website then login and perform a very sensitive function.  The login and subsequent functionality is hosted on a different site (sorry I can'be be more specific due to sensitivity)

Choices considered for the UI are:

1. A javascript overlay
2. A popup
3. Load in the full page

The current development and prototype user testing has been on an overlay with no problems. There is concern that an overlay does not show the address bar and the SSL certificate therefore is more susceptible to phishing.

A popup or a full page would be better in this respect but I have read studies that show users do not pay attention to passive indicators:
http://www.usablesecurity.org/emperor/

Popups also have the problem with popup blockers, the overlay looks the best and provides the least disruptive user experience, i.e. user feels they have not left the original site

So what is the best option considering security, usability and design?

Related question: is there any problems with loading an iframe within an overlay? e.g. scrollbars etc?

Edit: The question is more how to present the secure login page on an overlay, a popup or redirect to load the login in the full page. I'll edit the question to make this clear

Edit: Any links to research or studies showing increased phishing if an overlay is used would be very useful for making the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect the user to login on the secure login page and customize its look. Make sure the secure login pages url are the same every time. You might wanna have a look at how Stack Overflow (a big website for programmers) handle logins with OpenIDs.

Comment: The question is more how to present the secure login page on an overlay, a popup or redirect to load the login in the full page. I'll edit the question to make this clear

Comment: @Rakkhi yeah didnt I answer that? redirect! :)

Comment: Upvoted.  You really don't want to load a secure page inside an iframe of an unsecure page in a different domain.  It would be really prone to phishing as your users wouldn't ever expect to see the verified SSL stuff so if you were ever compromised no one would be the wiser.  Most users wouldn't know either way but hopefully at least one user would bring it to the companies attention.  In this case security definitely trumps usability and design.

Comment: @stefan thanks
@aliester the original page and the secure login page will both be over HTTPS not sure if that makes a difference to your answer. So even if most people do not pay attention to things like the address bar and SSL EV, padlock etc and other passive indicators, not using an overlay but loading the full page is the best way to go? Any links to research or studies showing increased phishing if an overlay is used would be very useful for making the case

Comment: @Rakkhi sorry got busy the last couple of days.  are both pages protected by the same SSL EV cert or different ones? Also if you point the iframe to a non-secure site does it create warnings that elements on the page are from an insecure source?

Comment: Different SSL EV certs. No effectively the flow is original site > user clicks button > original site calls web service on second site to authenticate and pass info >  second site returns URL which is loaded into the overlay > user logs in and continues interacting with the pages in the overlay > when finished closes overlay and returns to original site. Well that's how they have described it to me anyway, it is still in design and while there are demos no actualy proof of concept. Goal is to have no SSL warnings, I would have thought this is possible